# What are some good games for teaching maths to children?

Tags: education

I am due to teach maths to a ten-year-old. I'd like to try out some games such as Nim and Conway's Soldiers. I've found [this list on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aMathematical_games) but Googling for more just gives me a load of Flash games. I want something we can do with a pen and paper, or chequerboard and pebbles, stuff like that.

Are there any good educational games which aren't on the list and can be done without special equipment?

Comment: Not sure it's suitable to children, but may be inspiring: *[Winning Ways for your Mathematical Plays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winning_Ways_for_your_Mathematical_Plays)*.

Answer (score 1):

Mastermind is always a great one. You can introduce topics like permutations and combinatorics very subtly with it.

A new video game has been released very recently and it looks great. http://innertubegames.net/ As far as I know, it's completely free at the moment too! It might be a big challenging though.

Answer (score 0):

There are many variations of these games that are not described on wiki. For a example:

1) green hackenbush on trees (BTW nim is green hackenbush on bamboos) and on cactuses;

2) restricted variations of nim, when all heaps have different size and if heap A has more objects than heap B before turn, it should have more objects after turn;

3) one more nim with restriction that two heaps should not have the same size after turn.

Try your own ideas, may be some of them would be interesting.